# Swift Detecting which marker was pressed on google maps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

I'm wondering how to detect which marker was pressed on a map. I have few markers on map and class Marker in markers array downloaded from API, that contains some data. Now I'm wondering how send data to next VC after pressing marker. Is it good to send whole Array to the next VC, and then somehow get data through array on the other VC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `userData` property to store unique data that you want.

```
for (index,i) in markers.enumerated() {
      let marker = GMSMarker()
      marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(i.lat, i.lng)
      marker.userData = ["index": index]
      print("@@@\(i.id)")
      marker.title = i.name
      marker.map = mapView            
}
```

Performsegue in didTap method like this.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: marker)
    return true
}
```

Now in `prepareForSegue` get the index of object from `userData`.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "details" {
        var nextVC =  segue.destination as! VC2
        if let marker = sender as? GMSMarker,
           let dict = marker.userData as? [String:Int] {


             print(dict["index"])
            // use this array index to access object from array
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so here is what I done: 

I will put link to pastebin, because don't know how to add code in comment :P

http://pastebin.com/aeQHT9cL

Comment: Still getting empty dict.

http://pastebin.com/i6UEfq2R
everything seems ok

Comment: What if i will add in Marker-class index, and when I'm creating markers array with JSON parsing to every Marker. Is it easier to access it within class? I mean.. The worst thing is to send right data..

Comment: @Tonamini In Swift 3 signature of `prepareForSegue` ischange so replace your method with my one.

Comment: @Tonamini Have you changed `prepareForSegue` with my one is it working after that?

Comment: you are my God! <3 Everything works, it was optional, so just I had just to unwrap it :D Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tonamini Welcome mate :)

Comment: Okay. So just to clarify for better understanding of your code :D 
@Nirav D
We use userData to make Dict of indexes, prepare for segue let's us know what Marker was pressed, but when I'm trying to send data to the details VC it asks me for GMSMarker, and i want to pass Marker... was trying everything i think :<

Comment: @Tonamini Edit your question with new code and the issue that you are currently facing.

Comment: I don't want to edit it, because someone maybe in future will use it :)

Here is my problem: http://pastebin.com/9WenuRah

Comment: @Tonamini Can you add new question With more detail and your current issue if you don't want to edit this one.

Comment: @Tonamini You haven't respond is your problem solved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876232/passing-data-from-marker-to-other-vc

Was struggling all day with it...

Comment: Well, it has served me. Thank you