# Passing data from Marker to other VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

At the beggining of this post I would like thank @Nirav D for help :)

Ok. So the problem.

There is a class i want to pass with prepareForSegue func with google marker. How to do it?

Comment: Add the preparefor segue here too and your next viewcontroller code Also are not using userData like I have suggested in previous post of your.

Comment: What exception You are getting **was trying to get at least object from array, but it throws me exepction**?

Comment: you asked the same question twice?! @NiravD already had the solution on his answer to your previous post?!

Comment: you can put your marker-class object on the GMSMarker when you place it on map. and get it on didTap.

Comment: Okay. How can i Do it? Because marker in prepareforSegue is subclass of GMSMarker, how can i store class inside of marker? Or maybe just send few things like, lattitude, longitude and name?

Comment: @Tonamini What is the problem with the `userData` property that I have suggested. Are you not getting index of array?

Comment: No no. I'm getting index of array, but how can it help me to send data to the next VC? I think prepareForSegue was bad decision, and I will have to do it on CoreData..

Comment: @Tonamini What do you mean by CoreData here?, You have never specify that you are using CoreData?

Comment: So i have in the next ViewController var markerDetails as subclass of Marker class to get data from it, but don't know how to send marker class, because it is refferencing to GMSMarker in the sender

Comment: I'm not using CoreData yet, but wondering if it would be easier

Comment: @Tonamini Edit your question with `NextViewController` code, You want to pass selected marker object to next controller right?

Comment: @NiravD here you go :) There are some commented questions

Comment: I'm not adding alot to your code, because everytime I compile it, it crashes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too close to pass simply set the `passedMarker` with your array object.

```
if let marker = sender as? GMSMarker , //is it correct do declare marker as GMSMarker?
   let dict = marker.userData as? [String:Int] {

    let markerIndex = dict["index"]!
    nextVC.passedMarker = self.markers[markerIndex]
}
```

Now simply access `passedMarker` property in `viewDidLoad` of `VC3`.

Comment: this is quite strange, because I'm pretty i have tryed this yesterday like 15 times, and now when I'm writing your code, everything works...

Answer (score 0):

Edit this 
performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: marker)

To 
performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: self)